# Explain short circuit by current division

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, short-circuit

[image]

As the textbook page shows above, why do we conclude \$i_1 = 0\$ by merely concerning \$R_2 = 0\$ without concerning \$i\$ is a function of \$R_2\$, where:

$$i = {V\over R_{eq}} = V\cdot{{R_1+R_2}\over{R_1\cdot R_2}}$$

\$V\$ is the cross voltage of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, \$R_{eq}\$ is the equivalent resistance between two terminals.

Updates:

1. If these paralell resistors are excited by a non-0 DC voltage source \$V\$, and \$R_2\$ is infinitestimal (0+). Since \$i_1 = {V\over R_1}\$, where \$i_1\$ is a constant function of \$R_2\$. Would \$i_1\$ still be 0 in this case or \$i_1={V\over R_1}\$ (a defined non-0 value)?
   [image]
   Note that R2 is infinitestimal (0+), not 0, so that V across R2 could be non-0. Is this assumation plausible? Maybe I'm wrong, cuz \$V=0\$ is by the short circuit definition, hence can't be simulated by the infinitestimal condition.

I'm a Taiwanese and I'm sorry if I have any grammar mistakes.
Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Use Ohm's Law to compute V across R2. Use Ohm's Law again to compute I1.

Comment: @user_1818839
If we assume R2=infinitesimal, and we calculate V across R2 by ohm's law, V=i2*0, but how to know i is not infinity. If i=infinity, then V=indeterminant. Else if V(across R2)=0 why don't you say i2=0.

Comment: Your new update is not consistent with the schematic shown with the original question. You can't connect an ideal short circuit in parallel with an ideal non-zero voltage source. This violates the definitions of how these elements behave. So, the new question you asked is nonsensical. If there is an ideal short circuit then \$V\$ is zero **by definition**, and the voltage across a resistor parallel to the short is zero **by definition**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If R2=0, then the voltage across R2 is zero, regardless of any current flowing through it, V = I*R.

The current flowing through any finite resistance R1 with the same zero voltage across it will be zero, I=V/R.

This is an *ideal* circuit. If you're feeling uncomfortable that a real circuit wouldn't behave like this, then you're right, but your schematic is too simplified to show the 'not quite zero' resistance of a real 'short-circuit'. If you replace the idealised zero ohms short circuit with 1 mΩ, or 1 μΩ, then there will be a voltage across it, and some current will flow in R1. FWIW, a 1 m length of copper wire with 1 mm<sup>2</sup> cross section will have a resistance of about 17 mΩ at room temperature. Of course, if you have the opportunity to play with superconductors, then you can experience real R=0 behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the equation $$i = \frac{V}{R_eq}$$ is that it's an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form) because both \$V\$ and \$R_eq\$ are/tend to \$0\$.

\$V\$ is \$0\$ because, since the resistors are connected in parallel, \$V\$ across \$R_1\$ is the same as \$V\$ across \$R_2\$. Applying Ohm's law at \$R_2\$:

$$V = i_2R_2$$

you can see that when we make \$R_2 = 0\$, \$V\$ becomes \$0\$ (independently of \$i_2\$)

In the case of \$R_{eq}\$, it follows that:

$$\frac{1}{R_{eq}} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}$$

So you can see that when \$R_2\$ tends to 0, \$\frac{1}{R_2}\$ tends to infinity. This means that \$\frac{1}{R_{eq}}\$ tends to infinity, which means implies that \$R_{eq}\$ tends to \$0\$.

Alternatively, if you take:

$$R_{eq} = \frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

you can also see that, as \$R_2\$ gets closer to 0, so does \$R_{eq}\$.

Because of this, if you try to apply:

$$i = \frac{V}{R_{eq}}$$
You get an indeterminate state, \$\frac{0}{0}\$ and thus you can not use this equation to determine \$i\$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no disagreement between your two equations.  The first states that the current through R1 is zero.  All well and good.  The second specifies that the current through the parallel combination of R1 and the short will be infinite.  This is also all well and good, and does include the situation in which the current through R1 is zero and the current through R2 is infinite.

Comment: I know what you mean, but would much prefer to see it written as "current through" (and "voltage across").